# What is this condition syntax in react native code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, conditional-statements

This is part of the code I found for displaying spinner in react native

```
...
{this.state.loading &&
    <View style={styles.loading}>
      <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
    </View>
}
```

But what syntax is it? What does `this.state.loading &&` mean? 
Its different from inline condition.

Comment: render the `<View ...` only when `loading` is true. refer [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

Comment: It is not only React Native feature. It is a JS behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&&` operator is only evaluating the left side. If the result is true then the view is rendered. If it evaluates to false nothing is rendered.

Basically it is short for

```
{this.state.loading?
    <View style={styles.loading}>
        <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
    </View>
: null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's just a condition like ternary operator, if the first condition is true, it will render since the tag block (second condition) is always true.

```
{ condition &&
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
}
```